# A script that deletes extra spaces between letters in text

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, scripting

I have a text document that has a load of text which has an extra space added after every letter!

Example:

```
T h e  b o o k  a l s o  h a s  a n  a n a l y t i c a l  p u r p o s e  w h i c h  i s  m o r e  i m p o r t a n t…
```

Visually:

```
T␣h␣e␣␣b␣o␣o␣k␣␣a␣l␣s␣o␣␣h␣a␣s␣␣a␣n␣␣a␣n␣a␣l␣y␣t␣i␣c␣a␣l␣␣p␣u␣r␣p␣o␣s␣e␣␣w␣h␣i␣c␣h␣␣i␣s␣␣m␣o␣r␣e␣␣i␣m␣p␣o␣r␣t␣a␣n␣t…
```

Note that there is an ***extra*** space after every letter,
so there are two spaces between consecutive words.

Is there a way that I can get `awk` or `sed` to delete the extra spaces? 
(Unfortunately this text document is massive and
would take a very long time to go through manually.) 
<del>I appreciate that this is probably a much more complex problem to solve with just a simple bash script as there needs to be some sort of text recognition also.</del>

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: it is trivial to replace all spaces with nothing.. but I think you'd want to separate the words?

Comment: for ex: `echo 't h i s i s a n e x a m p l e' | sed 's/ //g'`

Comment: That doesn't limit the change to spaces between *letters*.  (Digits and punctuation aren't *letters*, for instance).  You can do this in sed with a loop.  This also is probably a duplicate.

Comment: As idea: try to add letter by letter in loop and check by something like `look` while get word, than go next

Comment: to restrict only between letters: `echo 'T h i s ; i s .a n 9 8 e x a m p l e' | perl -pe 's/[a-z]\K (?=[a-z])//ig'`

Comment: As you can see from the two good answers so far, a simple dictionary approach is insufficient.  The program would probably need to do two or more passes to find the longest words first.  Of course that would still be imperfect, but better.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: The [source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/c7047c52-d85b-4390-b7fc-5be63dc32072/view-source) of the original revision shows that the spaces between words were doubled. Why did you un-double them in your edit?

Comment: Hmmm.  I was convinced the last editor added those but you're right.  I rolled it back.

Comment: Are these really spaces, or is this UTF-16 from a Windows machine?

Comment: @countermode UTF-16 would also encode spaces between words with two bytes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following regex will remove the first space in any string of spaces.
That should do the job.

```
s/ ( *)/\1/g
```

So something like:

```
perl -i -pe 's/ ( *)/\1/g' infile.txt
```

...will replace infile.txt with a "fixed" version.

Comment: @terdon I've noticed in recent times that people have stopped writing perl pie scripts as `perl -pie` - as your edit shows. What's the rationale for this? The -pie has always worked well for me, and is a great mnemonic. Has -i's behavior changed to treat anything following as an extension, rather than only those things which begin with a dot? It would seem strange for them to break something so idiomatic.

Comment: Huh, well it's not an idiom I'm familiar with. Perl has been this way for as long as I've been using `-i`. On the other hand, I've only ever used it on Linux machines and I haven't known about it for more than a few years, so I can't speak as to its older behavior. On my machine though, this: `perl -pie 's/a/b/' f`, produces an error: `Can't open perl script "s/o/A/": No such file or directory`.  While `perl -i -pe 's/o/A/' f` works as expected. So yes, the `e` is taken as the backup extension.

Comment: Sadface. Ah, well, time moves on, and it just means I need to relearn a parameter order. Keeps my brain squishy, I guess. Thanks for letting me know, and for fixing my code!

Answer (score 18):

Use [`wordsegment`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wordsegment), a pure-Python word segmentation NLP package:

```
$ pip install wordsegment
$ python2.7 -m wordsegment <<<"T h e b o o k a l s o h a s a n a n a l y t i c a l p u r p o s e w h i c h i s m o r e i m p o r t a n t"
the book also has an analytical purpose which is more important
```

Comment: Using NLP is probably the most effective solution if there is nothing else to tell the words apart.  NLP performs better than a look-ahead dictionary in most cases.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the fact that the input includes double spaces between words, there is a much simpler solution.  You simply change the double spaces to an unused character, remove the spaces and change the unused character back to a space:

```
echo "T h e  b o o k  a l s o  h a s  a n  a n a l y t i c a l  p u r p o s e  w h i c h  i s  m o r e  i m p o r t a n t  " | sed 's/  /\-/g;s/ //g;s/\-/ /g'
```

...outputs:

> The book also has an analytical purpose which is more important

Comment: A sed command with a meaning "replace every occurence of a non-space character, followed by a space with just the corresponding non-space character" does the same:`sed -e "s/\([^ ]\) /\1/g"`

Comment: That is indeed a good alternative.  You should post it as an answer to get credit for it.

Answer (score 10):

Perl to the rescue!

You need a dictionary, i.e. a file listing one word per line. On my system, it exists as `/var/lib/dict/words`, I've also seen similar files as `/usr/share/dict/british` etc.

First, you remember all the words from the dictionary. Then, you read the input line by line, and try to add characters to a word. If it's possible, you remember the word and try to analyze the rest of the line. If you reach the end of the line, you output the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $words = '/var/lib/dict/words';
my %word;

sub analyze {
    my ($chars, $words, $pos) = @_;
    if ($pos == @$chars) {
        $_[3] = 1;  # Found.
        say "@$words";
        return
    }
    for my $to ($pos .. $#$chars) {
        my $try = join q(), @$chars[ $pos .. $to ];
        if (exists $word{$try}) {
            analyze($chars, [ @$words, $try ], $to + 1, $_[3]);
        }
    }
}


open my $WORDS, '<', $words or die $!;
undef @word{ map { chomp; lc $_ } <$WORDS> };

while (<>) {
    my @chars = map lc, /\S/g;
    analyze(\@chars, [], 0, my $found = 0);
    warn "Unknown: $_" unless $found;
}
```

For your input, it generates 4092 possible readings on my system.

Comment: fails test with spaced out version of `a cat a log` ie `a c a t a l o g`

Comment: @richard: OBOE, fixed. But it now generates too many possibilites, try to remove one letter words.

Comment: @richard You might fight this problem with help of a non-deterministic algorithm (e.g. all possible readings are stored) and apply a parser on it. Then you could filter all 4000 possible readings to the single one with the least error count.

Answer (score 6):

Note: this answer (like a few others here) is based on [an earlier version of the question](/revisions/309039/5) where words were not delimited. The newer version can be [trivially answered](/a/309143).

On an input like:

> `T h e b o o k a l s o h a s a n a n a l y t i c a l p u r p o s e w h i c h i s m o r e i m p o r t a n t`

You could try:

```
 $ tr -d ' ' < file | grep -oiFf /usr/share/dict/words | paste -sd ' '
 The book also has ana na l y tic al purpose which ism ore important
```

It processes left to right and find one longest word after the next.

Obviously, here, it's not the best selection of words as that sentence doesn't make any sense, but to come up with the right one, you'd need tools able to understand the grammar or meaning of the text or at least some statistical information on what words are likely to be found together to come up with the most probable set of words. Looks like the solution is a [specialised library as found by Lynn](/a/309074)

Comment: @terdon, see edit. The problem is that that question was changed from a complex and interesting one into a trivial one. Is there a way you could split it into the two questions that it was before and after the edit?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no. Still a clever trick though, even if not perfect.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question was trivial from the beginning — see [the first version](/revisions/309039/1) and [its source](/revisions/c7047c52-d85b-4390-b7fc-5be63dc32072/view-source).  Unfortunately, the OP didn't understand how Stack Exchange renders text, so the correct input text wasn't visible until [trichoplax](/users/189289/trichoplax) [fixed the formatting](/review/suggested-edits/158065) — and, even more unfortunately, it wasn't visible *then*, because the person who approved that edit immediately went and broke it.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Dewi Morgan's version, but with sed:

```
$ echo "f o o  t h e  b a r" | sed -r "s/[ ]{1}([^ ]{1})/\1/g"
foo the bar
```

Comment: That's GNU `sed` only and that's not equivalent to Dewi's. The standard `sed` equivalent of Dewi's would be `sed 's/ \( *\)/\1/g'`

Comment: note the "similar" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Although it could (and should) be done with a Perl one-liner, a small C parser would be very fast, too, and is also very small (and hopefully very correct):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char c1 = '\0', c2 = '\0', tmp_c;

  c1 = fgetc(stdin);
  for (;;) {
    if (c1 == EOF) {
      break;
    }
    c2 = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c2 == EOF) {
      if (c1 != ' ') {
        fputc(c1, stdout);
      }
      break;
    }
    if (c1 == c2 && c1 == ' ') {
      tmp_c = fgetc(stdin);
      if (tmp_c != EOF) {
        if (tmp_c != '\n') {
          ungetc(tmp_c, stdin);
          fputc(' ', stdout);
        } else {
          ungetc(tmp_c, stdin);
        }
      } else {
        break;
      }
    } else if (c1 != ' ') {
      fputc(c1, stdout);
    }
    c1 = c2;
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc-4.9 -O3 -g3  -W -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 lilcparser.c -o lilcparser
```

(programm is a bit less than 9kb)

Use in a pipe like e.g.:

```
echo "T h e  b o o k  a l s o  h a s  a n  a n a l y t i c a l  p u r p o s e  w h i c h  i s  m o r e  i m p o r t a n t  " | ./lilcparser
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work :

```
echo "<text here>" | sed -r 's/(\w)(\s)/\1/g'
```

The `sed` command captures two groups and returns only the first.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, I would do this:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    fstream is("test.txt", std::ios::in);

    char buff;
    vector<char>str;

    while (!is.eof()){is.get(buff);str.push_back(buff);} //read file to string

    for (int a=0;a<str.size();++a)if (str[a] == ' ' && str[a + 1] != ' ')str.erase(str.begin()+a);
    is.close();

    ofstream os("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc); //clear file for rewrite

    os.write(str.data(), str.size() * sizeof(char)); //write chars
    os.close();

    return 0;
    }
```

Will change the contents of the test text file, into the same string, but with spaces between letters removed. (It requires a space between every letter to be accurate).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'F o u r  s c o r e  a n d' | \
txr -t '(mapcar* (opip (split-str @1 "  ")
                       (mapcar (op regsub #/ / ""))
                       (cat-str @1 " "))
                 (get-lines))'
Four score and


$ txr -e '(awk (:begin (set fs "  "))
               ((mf (regsub #/ / ""))))'  # mf: modify fields
F o u r  s c o r e  a n d
Four score and


$ awk -F'  ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/ /,"",$i);print}'
F o u r  s c o r e  a n d
Four score and
```